# What is the Best Practice for Composite Key with JPA?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am creating a DB for my project and I am facing a doubt regarding best practice.
My concrete case is:
I have a table that stores the floors of a building called "floor"
I have a second table that stores the buildings called "building"
I have a third table that stores the relationship between them, called building_x_floor

The problem is this 3rd table.
What should I do?

1. Have only two columns, one holding a FK to the PK of building and another holding an FK to the PK of floor;
2. Have the two columns above and a third column with a PK and control consistency with trigger, forbidding to insert a replicated touple of (idbuilding, idfloor)?

My first thought was to use the first option, but I googling around and talking I heard that it is not always the best option.

So I am asking for guidance.
I am Using MySQL 5.6.17

Comment: Is there something else in the third table? If i's a pure join table, it shouldn't be mapped as an entity, and shouldn't have a third PK column. If it holds some other information, then it should be mapped as an entity, and have a single-column ID.

Comment: It is just a join table.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need third table. Because there is one-to-many relationship between `building` and `floor`.
So one building has many floors and a floor belongs to one building. Don't get things complicated. Even though you need a table with composite keys, you should be careful. You need to override `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

Comment: Agree.  But what happens if we are talking about self relationships?  For instance, an university discpline may or may not have a set of other disciplines as pre-requisites.  In that case what would be the best strategy?

Comment: Same for self relationship, it could be one-to-many (e.g. a course is dependent to multiple courses) or one-to-one ( e.g. one manger per person).
In self relationship entities you should put extra care when you are modifying an entity (e.g. updating primary key of an entity  - in a self relationship entity- might cause a problem) depending on the ORM you use or relationship you have. 
First, make sure your database design is good enough and you follow the third normal form of database. Then base on that you can set up your entities and relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not confortable with that approach.  I am not saying it is wrong or innapropriate, very far from that.  I am trying to understand how the informations would be organized and how performatic it would be.

If I have a 1:* relationship, like a student may be attending to more than one subject along its university course within a semester I would Have the 3rd table with (semester, idstudent, iddiscipline).

If I try to get rid of the join table my relationship would be made with a FK inside student table or inside subject table.  And it does not make sense to do that because student table is a table for a set of information related with registering the info of a person while the discipline table holds the data of a discipline, like content, hours...it is more a parametric table.

So I would need a table for the join.